# tabs in next js ssr best practice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

so consider that i have some tabs like below in ssr the html is like this:

```
<ul class="tab-heading">
  <li>
    tab1
  </li>
  <li>
    tab2
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="tab-content">
  <li>
    <Content1/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Content2/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see it can be structure of a simple tab logic, what i want is that the component in next not render content2 until i click on "tab2" but for seo, when getting html response from server we must be able to see that, how we can handle it in next js ssr page? (i also has virtualization in mind to for table with a lot of rows that must have html in response but not load rows until scroll, but answering this can be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers can understand react apps, so there is no worry about it.

It can crawl and search from every angle of your app.